# Java 8 and java 8

Tags: java, spring

When I upgraded to java 8 from java 6 on WIN 7 64 bit, I get exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'contactDao' defined in class path resource
[dao-ext3.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
Factory method [public static java.lang.Object com.s4hc.bes.ext.proxy.GenericExtProxyFactory.createInstance(com.s4hc.bes.ext.proxy.GenericExtProxy)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException
```

I have only changed java and it won't work. When I return to java 6 without any code change it works fine. 
Can anyone help? It looks to me as some spring problem. I'm planning to switch to newer version of spring too, but I doing this step by step.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll probably have to switch to a Spring version that officially supports Java 8, and thus probably has this bug fixed.

Comment: Java 8 is supported with at least Spring 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you all

Answer (score -1):

If you are upgrading to Java 8, make sure that you are using Spring 4. 
Spring 3 is supported only up to Java 7.